# Deleting a Node in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, binary-tree, nodes

I am trying to delete a node from a Binary Search Tree in scheme, but I am having trouble with the removing part of the code. How can I delete a node value without creating a new tree in scheme?

```
(define (delete-node v T)
  (cond ((null? T) '())
    ((< v (value T))
     (delete-node v (left T)))
    ((> v (value T))
     (delete-node v (right T)))
    (else
      (cond ((and (null? (right T))(not (null? (left T)))) '())
             ;promote the (left T) to the node
             ;repeat 
            ((and (null? (left T))(not (null? (right T)))) '())
             ;promote the (right T) to the node                                           
             ;repeat
```

Comment: I am not against creating a new tree if I need to for this code, I just couldn't see how this would work.

Comment: show us how you construct a sample tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For deleting a node in-place, your tree would have to be mutable - meaning: that either the value, the right subtree or the left subtree of a node can be modified in-place with new values.

It's easier to just build a new tree while traversing it, but even so there are a couple of implementation choices that must be made. Here's a sketch of a solution:

```
(define (delete-node v T)
  (cond ((null? T) '())
        ((< v (value T))
         ; see how we build the new tree
         (make-node (value T)
                    (delete-node v (left T))
                    (right T)))
        ((> v (value T))
         ; see how we build the new tree
         (make-node (value T)
                    (left T)
                    (delete-node v (right T))))
        (else
         (cond ((and (null? (right T)) (and (null? (left T))))
                ; this case was missing
                '())
               ((and (null? (right T)) (not (null? (left T))))
                (left tree))
               ((and (null? (left T)) (not (null? (right T))))
                (right tree))
               (else
                ; implementation detail: if both subtrees of the
                ; node to be deleted are non-null, who should take
                ; the place of the deleted node? the new subtree
                ; must preserve the order property of the tree
                <???>)))))
```

The interesting case is marked with `<???>`. There are several options, it's up to you to pick and implement one. For instance, in a sorted tree (which I assume is the case here), one could pick the biggest element from the left subtree, and recursively delete it before moving it into place.

Notice that if the tree has to remain *balanced* after deleting the node  (according to the balancing definition in use), the algorithm is trickier - I'm assuming that the tree is not balanced.

Comment: Should I also have a case to check if both the right T and left T are null, and then return '()? Also, can I simply put (left T) or (right T) into the else statement? I am having trouble imagining why this would cause me problems. I know I need either the largest value in the left subtree or the smallest in the right subtree, but I don't know why.

Comment: 1) Yes, I updated my answer. 2) No, you'd be deleting a whole subtree if you did that in the last `else` 3) Because you have to recreate a new subtree that it's also sorted. Take a look at a good algorithms book or look for online animations showing the deletion process, it'll make things clear